# Better to filter JMS message by topic name or String Property?

Tags: jms, spring-jms, activemq-artemis

Using Apache ActiveMQ Artemis, is it preferred to have one topic with `String` properties used to differentiate them or many topics?  e.g., should publishers do this:

```java
jmsTemplate.convertAndSend("quotes", quote, m -> {
   m.setStringProperty("symbol", "MSFT");
   return m;
});
```

or this?

```java
jmsTemplate.convertAndSend("quotes.MSFT", quote, m -> {
   m.setStringProperty("symbol", "MSFT");
   return m;
});
```

Note that I can not just do:

```java
jmsTemplate.convertAndSend("quotes.MSFT", quote);
```

because I need the symbol property as `default-last-value-key`:

```xml
<address-setting match="quote.#">
  <retroactive-message-count>100000</retroactive-message-count>
  <default-last-value-key>symbol</default-last-value-key>
  <default-non-destructive>true</default-non-destructive>
```

There could be 100,000 symbols. Would it be terrible to have so many pub/sub topics created?

Most will have no subscribers but will retain the last value using Retroactive Addresses.  I will have consumers in Java and Python (STOMP).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally speaking, there's nothing intrinsic about ActiveMQ Artemis that would necessarily push you one way or the other.

However, your use-case is rather unique with the retroactive-address + LVQ configuration. My concern here with using a single address is that if there really are 100,000 symbols and the last value for each symbol should be retained then the ring-queue backing the retroactive address will potentially need to be 100,000 messages deep which means that every time a subscription queue is created on that address then the broker will have to process all those messages. I expect that would be a significant burden on the broker.

Therefore, at this point I'd say that an address for each symbol is likely the best. Then the `retroactive-message-count` can be `1`.

Ultimately my best advice would be to actually test these two different configurations with a production-like load and then choose the one that best fits your use-case in terms of performance, manageability, etc. The devil is always in the details with this sort of thing. There are too many moving parts and unspoken requirements to provide an authoritative recommendation in a context like this.

Comment: When doing address-per-symbol,  CPU and memory usage shoots way up and the web mgmt console becomes unresponsive and I have to kill artemis.   Should I be able to create 100k addresses?  Artemis does not appear to love it.  I don't need these to persist msgs in case of a failure.   Does Artemis not index the stored message by default-last-value-key to speed finding what to send on connection of a client? Also, if creating addresses is expensive, should I do it programatically at startup instead of upon msg arrival?

Comment: At what exact point does the CPU and memory usage shoot way up? Do you have thread dumps and/or heap dumps which indicate where CPU and memory were being used? [This recent thread](https://lists.apache.org/thread/oj0st1bfco738snczs88f8d9khnsb7k9) on the ActiveMQ users mailing list may help.

Comment: You should be able to create 100k addresses no problem. I just ran a simple test on my laptop creating 100k addresses with 1 queue each and it finished in around 7 seconds. There is no arbitrary limit to the number of addresses and queues you can create. The only limit is the environment (e.g. heap size, CPU, etc.).

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're asking about indexing "the stored message." Can you clarify your question?

Comment: When a client subscribes to a last-value topic does the broker have to iterate over stored messages to find one with the matching default-last-value-key or can the broker look up the required message using the key as an index?

Comment: Technically speaking, there is no such thing as a "last-value topic." There is only a last-value queue (i.e. LVQ). When a JMS client subscribes to a topic the broker responds by creating a multicast queue on the address whose name matches the JMS topic. The broker applies the `default-last-value-key` to the queue when it is created. Since that value is `true` in your case then when messages are sent to the address and routed to the queue LVQ semantics are enforced. There is no "index" or "look up" involved in this process.